# Удалять ли "Всё, я разобралась"?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, очередь-проверок, удаление-вопросов, самоответы

Достаточно часто встречаю ситуацию, когда топикстартер пишет ответ из которого сложно понять, что за решение применено. В пределе это звучит просто как "всё, разобрался, вопрос закрыт". Последний пример [см. тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/879322/213987).

Примерно такие же случаи могут быть немного более подробными, содержащие небольшие намёки на ход мысли или направление решения вопроса, например:

- всем спасибо, нашёл баг в .htaccess
- разобрался, сам тупанул не на тот сервер отправлял

И так далее.

Вижу два сложившихся подхода к проверке таких ответов в очереди "Сообщения низкого качества":

- Ответ оставляем, чтобы в статистике было видно, что вопрос получил решение (топикстартер может даже его отметить галкой через два дня) - и рассчитываем, что может быть когда-нибудь ответ будет подробнее расписан.
- Ответ не несёт пользы другим участникам, поэтому нужно ответ удалить (преобразовав в комментарий) и подумать над тем, чтобы закинуть ---гранатку--- голос за закрытие в сам вопрос (как правило - "вызыван опечаткой или не воспроизводится").

Как же всё-таки поступать правильно в подобных случаях? Есть какой-то общий рецепт или приходится положиться на революционное чутье?

Comment: Сегодня был [задан вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7839/213987), который продолжает тему коротких вопросов на грани - и там рассматриваются как раз случаи когда чуть более подробные ответы, но ненамного.

Answer (score 10):

А вы не смотрите на то, что ответ от автора. Рассуждайте так, будто ответ от другого участника. Если бы другой участник ответил "всё, я помог" — это как-то поможет другим с похожей проблемой? Нет.

Ну вот и всё — значит, нужно удалять.

Другое дело, если в ответе будет **указано, в чём именно** была проблема и **как** автор её исправил, тогда ответ нужно оставить.

Answer (score 6):

Удалять, однозначно. Можно без преобразования в комментарий. Именно для того, чтобы в статистике вопрос не был виден как получивший решение - ведь решения-то на сайте еще нет.